# Is it impossible developing with fastApi, uvloop, windows?

Tags: python, uvloop

I'm learning `fastapi` from Youtube class
I succeeded. except for the `[uvloop]` module
I realized that `uvloop` doesn't install in windows and my development environment is **Windows + PyCharm**.
How are others using this module? Are they only using mac?
What should I do?

Should I view other videos or remove `uvloop`? or replace `uvloop`?
Help me.

Comment: Welcome! Your question isn't a good fit for SO as asked. You're asking us to answer several questions, with no explanation of what you've tried or the problems you've encountered. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and all their linked pages.

Answer (score 3):

Fastapi itself does not depend on uvloop. The transient extra dependency UVIcorn installed with ao called standard extras however does. However, UVicorn[standard] is just an extra dependency and not a required one. So if you just install fastapi without any extras and uvicorn without extras you should be good to go.

Comment: thanks guy. i will try without uvloop

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and discovered that I don't need to install uvloop if I am using windows. My fastapi app runs well without it.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop fastAPI applications on `pycharm + windows` by creating new fastAPI project directly from pycharm menu.

If you generated a fastAPI application using `openapi`, then use docker to develop your fastAPI application with pycharm as in the picture below.

[image: configuration for docker + pycharm]